# Ошибка подключения к бд firebird на линукс

Tags: linux, firebird

При подключении к бд, которая была изначально, всё нормально. Но если я пытаюсь подключиться к бд, которую создал через терминал, то выбивает ошибку, что пользователь не имеет привилегий.

```
*** IBPP::SQLException ***
Context: Database::Connect
Message: isc_attach_database failed

SQL Message : -551
This user does not have privilege to perform this operation on this object.

Engine Code    : 335544352
Engine Message :
no permission for read-write access to database /var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/first_database.fdb
```

Причем это при подключении от любого пользователя. Что от админа, что от обычного.
Подключаюсь через GUI FlameRobin. Да и при подключении через терминал тоже самое выбивает.

Comment: Ну так спросите, что это за _This user_, который _does not have privilege to perform this operation on this object_. А ещё от имени sysdba  спросите, кто и какие права имеет на эту свежесозданную БД. Ну или при создании (или сразу после создания, прямо из того же терминала) базы укажите, кому и что в этой БД можно - тот, кто создал БД, имеет необходимые для этого права,- а заодно полюбопытствуйте, whoami.

Comment: Вопрос: как это сделать ?

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался.

Если вы получаете сообщение об ошибке, такое как «Statement failed, SQLCODE = -551 no permission for read-write access to database /var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/employee.fdb», это означает, что серверный процесс не может прочитать или получить доступ на запись в файл базы данных. Измените владельца базы данных для пользователей firebird:

```
**# cd /var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/**

**# chown firebird:firebird employee.fdb**
```